# How to zoom Orthographic projection with geoviews?

Tags: matplotlib, cartopy, orthographic, hvplot, geoviews

I know with matplotlib i can zoom on a orthographic projection with something like that :

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection=ccrs.Orthographic(-40, 20)
ax.set_extent([-110, 30, -20, 65])
```

How can i do this with hvplot / Geoviews / Holoviews ? All exemples i have found don't zoom on this specific projection,

actual example :

```
import xarray as xr
import hvplot.pandas
import holoviews as hv
import geoviews.feature as gf
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

proj = ccrs.Orthographic(-40, 20)
lon_range = (-110, 30)
lat_range = (-20, 65)

ds = xr.open_mfdataset(liste_files, engine="netcdf4")

pd_times = ds.to_dataframe() # <-- i cannot plot points with xarray directly, don't know why
points = pd_times.hvplot.points(x="longitude", y="latitude", c="sat1", projection=proj)

points = hv.Overlay(aff)

layout = (gf.ocean
    * points
    * gf.land.options(scale="50m")
    * gf.coastline.options(scale="50m")
    * gf.rivers
    * gf.lakes 
).opts(
    width=500, 
    projection=proj
)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Founded : you need to add `xlim` and/or `ylim` in the argument of hvplot.

```
points = pd_times.hvplot.points(x="longitude", y="latitude", c="sat1", projection=proj, xlim=lon_range, ylim=lat_range)
```